# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘find_middle_artist’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

So, I'm making a program that sorts a list of artists with three values as their members. But every time I compile, I get the title error. I am casting, and cannot see why this is happening.

```
struct artist *sort_artists(struct play *artistl, int criterion){

   if (!(criterion == PLAYCOUNT || criterion == ARTISTID)){
     printf("[ERROR]: Incorrect Criterion");
     return (struct artist *)artistl;
   }
   else{
     if (criterion == PLAYCOUNT){
      struct artist *m = NULL;
      struct artist *x = NULL;
      struct artist *y = NULL;
      if (artistl == NULL || artistl->next == NULL)
        return (struct artist *)artistl;

      x = (struct artist *)artistl;
      m = find_middle_artist((struct artist *)artistl);
      y = m;
      m->next = NULL;
      return merge(sort_artists(x, criterion), sort_artists(y, criterion));
    }
  else if (criterion == ARTISTID){
    struct artist *m = NULL;
    struct artist *x = NULL;
    struct artist *y = NULL;

    if (artistl == NULL || artistl->next == NULL)
      return (struct artist *)artistl;

    x = (struct artist *)artistl;
    m = find_middle_artist(artistl);
    y = m;
    m->next = NULL;
    return merge(sort_artists(x, criterion), sort_artists(y, criterion));
  }
```

}
}

Comment: You need to provide us with `find_middle_artist` signature... Typecasting has nothing to do with it, its something else.

Comment: In the first call you cast it, but not in the second.